# Code from option tag sends blank data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I built a site that stores Service Mechanic customers to a db. It has function to update an entry. I had one Drop down select field working fine (and it still does). But the second one I added after the fact returns only blank for information.

Here is my code.

```
include('connect.php');

$table='currentJobs';
$tableMap=array('Date','Name','Phone','Bike_Year','Bike_Model','Current_Status','SType','Mechanic','Revenue','Notes');

$sqlArray=array();

foreach ($tableMap AS $key){
    $sqlArray[]="`".$key."`='".mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST[$key],$dbLink)."'";
}

$sql="UPDATE `".$table."` SET ".join(',',$sqlArray)." WHERE `id`='".$_POST['id']."'";

if (mysql_query($sql,$dbLink)){
    echo 'Data for <i>' .$_POST['Name'].'</i> was successfully updated <br />'.$sql.'.';
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry, could not process the following sql: <br /><code>'.$sql.'</code>';
    echo mysql_errno($dbLink) . ": " . mysql_error($dbLink). "\n";
}

mysql_close($dbLink);
```

It is returning this:

```
Data for Test User was successfully updated 
UPDATE `currentJobs` SET `Date`='04/14/2013',`Name`='Test User',`Phone`='1234567890',`Bike_Year`='2001',`Bike_Model`='FXD',`Current_Status`='Checked In',`SType`='',`Mechanic`='All',`Revenue`='0',`Notes`='' WHERE `id`='55'.
```

My Form looks like this:

```
<form action="updated.php" method="POST" name="dataForm" id="dataForm">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
    <label>Arrival<input type="text" name="Date" value="<?php echo $row['Date']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Name<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Phone Number<input type="text" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $row['Phone']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Bike Year<input type="text" name="Bike_Year" value="<?php echo $row['Bike_Year']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Bike Model<input type="text" name="Bike_Model" value="<?php echo $row['Bike_Model']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Current Status<!--Update Status types on two pages-->
        <select name="Current_Status" form="dataForm" value="<?php echo $row['Current_Status']; ?>">
            <option value="Checked In">Checked In</option>
            <option value="Inline For Service">Inline For Service</option>
            <option value="In Service">In Service</option>
            <option value="On Hold - Parts on Order">On Hold - Parts on Order</option>
            <option value="On Hold - Parts to Paint">On Hold - Parts to Paint</option>
            <option value="On Hold - Waiting To Hear From Customer">On Hold - Waiting To Hear From Customer</option>
            <option value="Test Ride">Test Ride</option>
            <option value="Completed - Awaiting Pick Up">Completed - Awaiting Pick Up</option>
            <option value="Picked Up">Picked Up</option>
        </select>
    </label><br />
    <!--update Service Type in two pages.-->
    <label>Service Type</label>
        <select name="SType" form="" value="<?php echo $row['SType']; ?>">
            <option value="Spec Service Interval">Spec Service Interval</option>
            <option value="Interim Service">Interim Service</option>
            <option value="Diagnostics">Diagnostics</option>
            <option value="Tires">Tires</option>
            <option value="Engine– Light Work (1-3 hrs)">Engine– Light Work (1-3 hrs)</option>
            <option value="Engine– Medium Work (3-8 hrs)">Engine– Medium Work (3-8 hrs)</option>
            <option value="Engine– Heavy Work (8-24 hrs)">Engine– Heavy Work (8-24 hrs)</option>
            <option value="Drivetrain– Light">Drivetrain– Light</option>
            <option value="Drivetrain - Heavy">Drivetrain - Heavy</option>
            <option value="Dyno Tune">Dyno Tune</option>
        </select>
    <br />
    <label>Mechanic Assigned<input type="text" name="Mechanic" value="<?php echo $row['Mechanic']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Final Revenue<input type="text" name="Revenue" value="<?php echo $row['Revenue']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <label>Notes<input type="text" name="Notes" value="<?php echo $row['Notes']; ?>"/></label><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" style="color:#000000;" />
</fieldset>
```

Why will the second select not send data?

Comment: Your first `select` has been given a `form="dataForm"` but not for `<select name="SType" form=""`. Try giving it a value.

Comment: Actually, try removing the `form=""` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` tag doesn't have an attribute called `value`.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Update:

Something like this would be more useful:

```
<label>Service Type</label>
    <select name="SType" form="dataForm">
    <?php
    $Stypes = array(
    "Spec Service Interval",
    "Interim Service",
    "Diagnostics",
    "Tires",
    "Engine– Light Work (1-3 hrs)",
    "Engine– Medium Work (3-8 hrs)",
    "Engine– Heavy Work (8-24 hrs)",
    "Drivetrain– Light",
    "Drivetrain - Heavy",
    "Dyno Tune",
    );

    foreach($Stypes as $value){
      if ($value==$row['SType']){
        echo "<option value=\"$value\" selected=\"selected\">value</option>";  
      } else {
        echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";  
      }
    }

    ?>

    </select>
```

Assuming you're pulling `$row['Stype']` back from the database.

Also as @Fred was saying, you probably need to specify a *form id* for the `form` attribute if you're using HTML5 (although this does not work in IE... yet).

You can also do a `print_r($_POST)` for debugging on the page where you're doing the insertion, just to verify what's happening.

Comment: It does have a `value`, it's this => `<select name="SType" form="" ` that doesn't have anything set.

Comment: But not an attribute `value` ;)

Comment: @cpattersonv1 is right. If you want to set the select option based on your value, you will need to add PHP code to each option to check against the value for that option and set `selected="selected"` for the matching option.

Comment: The OP said that the first one is working and has a value set for `value="<?php echo $row['Current_Status'];`, the 2nd being `value="<?php echo $row['SType'];`, so there is a value set to it. May or may not be the cause.

Comment: Your answer shouldn't have the same form name as stated `<select name="SType" form="dataForm">`, maybe `dataForm2` or something along the line. His `<select name="Current_Status" form="dataForm"` is already called that.

Comment: @Fred We're not declaring a new form, you can actually call multiple forms, so basically the form id is telling the `select` which forms it can belong to. He's already provided an id to the form itself. The id for the select is simply `id`.

Comment: @Fred It would really only matter if they were using more than one form and this was being reused in a different form as well. Otherwise it's extra.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 I won't disagree, however he should probably remove his `form=""` altogether. `<form` has already been declared.

Comment: @Fred Here's a reference for the new attribute in HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Comment: @cpattersonv1 Thanks, I've seen it often ;-) Personally, I think this question is `dead in the water`. The OP never once said a thing about comments and your answer. I'd call this `[closed]`.

Comment: Wow, So simple. Removing the Form attribute to both select's fixed the issue.

I originally had both set to the same and removed the second during troubleshooting, but I never tried removing them both.

Thank you all for the suggestions. Was great reading the different points of view.

@ anon cpattersonv1, thanks for the suggestion of setting my select lists into an array. But i am not sure how much more useful it would be other than maybe preventing some typo's while typing out the form. Could you explain more usefulness to it?

THanks,

Comment: You're actually performing the check to see if the value is set with the loop. It's easier to do that with the array because you can loop through the values. Also going forward if you decided to store the options in the database (in the case of a CMS) you could pull them back out using arrays.

Comment: THanks this is quickly reaching a small cms, This is my first db project, and I quickly see how powerful it is. I still don't understand all all the commands but it'll come. I appreciate the response.